# Map entities by custom column

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I mapped 2 entities in OneToMany relation.

> Countries Entity

```
class Countries
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->areas = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $country

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Areas", mappedBy="country")
     */
    private $areas;

    /**
     * @return Collection\Area[]
     */
    public function getAreas() {
        return $this->areas;
    }

}
```

> Areas Entity

```
class Areas
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $area;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Countries", inversedBy="area")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $country;

    public function getCountry() : Countries {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(Countries $countries) {
        $this->country = $countries;
    }

}
```

In my MySQL I see that they are mapped by Countries ID, so in db 1 record will looks like

> 1 2 Ile-De-France

I want to insert Countries Name

> 1 France Ile-De-France

Where can I set what column I want to use in mapping? 
I know I can always do $country->getName($id), but I prefer have clear view in DB.
Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's done, but you should keep the `id` anyway...
Else when you check the association mapping in the console, it will show "errors"

<kbd>**Area Entity**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Countries", inversedBy="area")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country", referencedColumnName="country", nullable=true)
 */
private $country;
```

Comment: I understand that it's probably less efficient but my DB will be small.

Comment: Right now, in method $area->setCountry($country Object) I have error 'undefined index $country'. Do you know something about it?

Comment: Not sure... I think you should make a new question, I can't tell without the complete code and complete error message... add a reply here with the question link, I will look it tomorrow in the morning